# Why does my 2013 Honda Fit's horn sound when I am jump starting my car?

Tags: honda, jump-start, alarm

I had to jump start my car recently, and couldn't get the horn to turn off for a long time. I'm still not sure what actually caused it to stop. The horn sounded on and off continuously from the moment I finished hooking up the cables.

Next time I jump start my car, what should I do to make sure the horn doesn't sound, or turn it off

Comment: @MarkJohnson 2013... added it to the question.

Comment: PS - I answered my own question, but if somebody comes up with a better/more helpful answer, I'd be delighted to accept that. So, I'll leave it open for a couple more days.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your car thinks it is being stolen - jump starting a car looks a lot like hot-wiring a car to the computer. You need to do something that tells your car "it's OK, I own you". You can do this right after hooking up the cables, but before starting the engine, to minimize the annoyance to your neighbors.

- If you have a remote door key, lock and unlock the doors with the remote, or
- Unlock the driver side door with the key